# How to transfer files from linux to iphone?

Tags: linux, gnome, error-handling, ios, iphone

I have the `libimobiledevice` family and `ifuse` package installed. When I connect my iPhone to Linux via USB cable I get the prompt to allow access. When I confirm, I can access the `DCIM` folder on gnome file explorer. However no other folders appear. Also I can only move photos and videos from the phone to my desktop and not the other way around. When I try to do that, I get an error:

```
There was an error copying the file into gphoto2://-Apple_Inc._iPh...123456789AB/DCIM/202304__.
Error writing file: -108: No such file or directory
```

How can I access documents other than photos and videos? How can I inject a file into iphone from linux?

Answer (score 9):

By default, connecting an iPhone to a Linux computer via USB only mounts the DCIM folder, which contains photos and videos. To access other folders and files on your iPhone, you can use a tool called `iFuse`.

```
sudo apt-get install ifuse
mkdir ~/iphone
ifuse ~/iphone
```

This will mount the iPhone file system under the `~/iphone` directory. You should now be able to access all the files on your iPhone using the file explorer.

To inject a file into the iPhone from Linux, you can simply copy the file to the appropriate directory in the iPhone file system. For example, to copy a file called `example.txt` to the Documents folder on the iPhone, you can do the following:

```
cd ~/iphone/Documents
cp /path/to/example.txt .
```

Note that you may need to eject the iPhone from the computer before the file is visible on the iPhone. You can do this by running the following command:

```
fusermount -u ~/iphone
```

Comment: ifuse worked thanks, I can transfer files both ways. But still I can't open transferred pictures at Photos app